# Understanding Scapy / Python class mechanics

Tags: python

I’m learning Scapy, and have come across something I’ve never seen before.

After importing scapy like this in iPython:

```
from scapy.all import *
```

I started learning from various tutorials. I learned that I can create a network package object like this:

```
packet = IP()/ICMP()
```

It seems that I can create a single object from two functions. I’m trying to figure out the mechanics behind this.

What does the ‘/‘ do?

Could I create the same packet by writing something like:

```
packet = IP()
packet = packet + ICMP()
```

Is that functionality piggybacking on basic python mechanics or is the ‘/‘ part of Scapy somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The `/` adds a layer to the object. You cannot add layers together in your example or you will get a `TypeError`.